# Compiz Water Effect - Does it work in Cinnamon?

Tags: 16.04, compiz, cinnamon

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with the Cinnamon desktop enviroment, and I am trying to get the Compiz Water Effect to work.

Previously, I didn't have that effect in Compiz, but thanks to the Synaptic package manager, I could enable the extra effects.

Once I got the effect, I enabled it and set a keybinding. But it doesn't seem to work. I tried checking KDE compatibility, GNOME compatibility and MATE compatibility, but none of them makes the effect work.

My Compiz settings:

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

Any ideas? Thank you!